# Javascript : can I re-order indexes of elements after an insertBefore or an appendChild method?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 div width class="childContainer" inside a parent container, like below :

```
<div id="parentContainer">

    <div class="childContainer"></div>
    <div class="childContainer"></div>
    <div class="childContainer"></div>

</div>
```

I can access these elements with :

```
parentContainer = document.getElementById("parentContainer");
childContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("childContainer");
```

Then, I move the first childContrainer to the last position by using :

`parentContainer.appendChild(childContainer[0]);`

So the element indexes of child containers become : 1, 2, 0 instead of 0, 1, 2.

But I want to re-order theses indexes so that element index 1 become 0, element index 2 become 1, and element index 0 become 2.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Indexes update automatically after every DOM manipulation. So don't worry about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `childContainers` you're creating an [`HTMLCollection` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). And:

> An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.

This means when you run `parentContainer.appendChild(childContainer[0]);` the `HTMLCollection` is updated, resulting in:

```
{
  "0": <div class="childContainer">1</div>,
  "1": <div class="childContainer">2</div>,
  "2": <div class="childContainer">0</div>,
  "length": 3,
  "item": function item() { [native code] },
  "namedItem": function namedItem() { [native code] }
}
```

which has reordered the elements so 0 is now 2, 1 is now 0, and 2 is now 1.

Here's an example - we'll append the first element to the end, then `console.log` the `childContainers` to see the indexes have changed.

```js
parentContainer = document.getElementById("parentContainer");
childContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("childContainer");

parentContainer.appendChild(childContainers[0]);

console.log(childContainers)
```

```html
<div id="parentContainer">

    <div class="childContainer">0</div>
    <div class="childContainer">1</div>
    <div class="childContainer">2</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) like this:

```
parentContainer.insertBefore(childContainer[0], childContainer[0]);
```